# Java: Usar jackson-databind en eclipse

Tags: java, jackson

Con este link: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind, descargué el .jar de jackson-databind para usar la clase ObjectMapper, en el github source-code ahi está la clase pero cuando añado el .jar a mi projecto no aparece la clase ObjectMapper(pero si se añade el .jar correctamente)

En el github le di click en "javadoc": https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHz6W.jpg,
y en la pagina que me manda el github le di click donde circulé: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyCP7.jpg

Comment: Prueba con el bundle de [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.13.2.2). En ese enlace, clickeas `bundle` y lo descargas. Lo que te descargaste en javadoc fue pura documentación.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que probablemente necesitarás también incluir [Jackson Annotations](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.13.2) y [Jackson Core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.13.2), por ello si es posible, por favor usa maven.